# Section becomes scrollable on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I don't know why, but only on Safari a section of a webpage I am working on becomes scrollable.

It is the only section which happens and it's the only browser on which this occurs.

Can anyone help me figure this one out?

Link to the webpage, if you want to inspect the code: http://sistemecreative.ro/demo-istoma/

[image: Here is a screenshot of the section]

Answer (score 0):

I decided, as a workaround, to make both the left and right divs and their wrapper the same height using a fixed value.